# Inconsistent link hover behavior in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

With this new beta theme, the hover behavior for the top links seems to be inconsistent in Chrome: `Questions`, `Tags`, `Badges`, and `Unanswered` immediately get highlighted with the hover color (no animation) while `Users` and `Ask Question` correctly animate to the hover color. I've only been able to reproduce this on Chrome for those 4 links on CR; all links in other beta sites behave correctly in Chrome and all links on CR behave correctly in Firefox.

Comment: I think that you shoud report this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126185/177799), as it was suggested in the [New Beta Theme Launched](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/485/10415).

Comment: @RikPoggi: i don't think so because i can't reproduce on any other beta sites

Comment: This is actually a webkit issue. Chrome ignores CSS transition on visited links. I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @Jin: ah, interesting :) thanks for the response!

Comment: btw, looks like it [will be fixed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245#c52) in Chrome 18